# How to export Pyspark dataframe to csv file by date

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, export-to-csv

I have a Pyspark dataframe which consist of dates and statements(2 different columns). I want to export all of the statements to differenct csv files based on unique dates. How do I do that? For example, I would have a csv file called 01012016.csv for Jan 1 which would consist of "Hello World" and "Hello World2" and so on throughout the month. At the end of the month, I want to compile all of the statements in one big csv file called Jan2016.csv, Feb2016.csv

Dates      Statements

2016/01/01 Hello World

2016/01/01 Hello World2

2016/01/02 Hello World2

....

2016/02/30 Hello World31

Comment: Which is really your question? Do you need to know how to convert a dataframe to csv?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a writer function and use that with `foreachPartition`. Here's an example.

```
# input dataframe
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['dt', 'statement']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.col('dt').cast('date')). \
    show()

# +----------+------------+
# |        dt|   statement|
# +----------+------------+
# |2016-01-01| hello world|
# |2016-01-01|hello world2|
# |2016-01-03| hello world|
# |2016-01-02|hello world2|
# +----------+------------+
```

Create a function to write values in a file

```
def write_to_csv(theRow):
    for i, row in enumerate(theRow):
        dt, statement, fname = row
        if i == 0:
            txt = open(r"./drive/MyDrive/{0}.txt".format(fname), "w")
            txt.write(statement)
            txt.close()
        else:
            txt = open(r"./drive/MyDrive/{0}.txt".format(fname), "a")
            txt.write('\n')
            txt.write(statement)
            txt.close()
```

Use the aforementioned function within `foreachPartition`.

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['dt', 'statement']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.col('dt').cast('date')). \
    withColumn('fname', func.date_format('dt', 'yyyyMMdd')). \
    repartition('dt'). \
    foreachPartition(write_to_csv)
```

If the location is accessible by your nodes, the files should now be present there.